# Approximate/estimate the ratio of two multidimensional constrained integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, boolean-computation, constraint

I have a hypothesis that a certain "qubit-qutrit separability probability" should assume the value $\frac{5}{3} \left(112 \pi ^2-1105\right) \approx 0.659488$. In its  initial formulation, this is a 15-dimensional problem. I believe that it can be reduced to the computation of the ratio of one nine-dimensional constrained integration to an eight-dimensional one (and upon further reflection to the ratio of one five-dimensional constrained integration to a six-dimensional one.

These two integrals appear presently not to be exactly computable.
(I think it is too large--plus including a cosine function--for the application of the GenericCylindricalDecomposition command.) So, I would like at least some numerical evaluation of their ratio, to test the plausibility of the hypothesis.

There are two sets of constraints--the first pertaining to the positivity of a $6 \times 6$ "density matrix" with complex off-diagonal entries, and the second to the positivity of the "partial transpose" of the density matrix.

Let us denote the first set of constraints by

```
A = r[1, 4]^2 + r[3, 4]^2 < 1
 && (-1 + r[1, 6]^2) (-1 + r[3, 4]^2) + r[1, 4]^2 (-1 + r[3, 6]^2) > r[3, 6] (2 Cos[t[1, 4] - t[1, 6] - t[3, 4] + t[3, 6]] r[1, 4] r[1, 6] r[3, 4] + r[3, 6])
```

and the second set by

```
B = r[1, 4]^2 + U r[1, 6]^2 < 1
 && (-1 + U r[1, 6]^2) r[3, 4]^2 + U r[3, 6] (-2 Cos[t[1, 4] - t[1, 6] - t[3, 4] + t[3, 6]] r[1, 4] r[1, 6] r[3, 4] + (-1 + r[1, 4]^2) r[3, 6]) > U (-1 + r[1, 4]^2 + U r[1, 6]^2).
```

(The notation could, of course, be streamlined--as it stands now, the indices refer to the entries of the density matrix, with the $r$'s being radial variables and the $t$'s being angular ones.)

The eight-dimensional denominator integral is

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[A] v,
  {r[1, 4], 0, 1}, {r[1, 6], 0, 1}, {r[3, 4], 0, 1}, {r[3, 6], 0, 1}, {t[1, 4], 0, 2 Pi}, {t[1, 6], 0, 2 Pi}, {t[3, 4], 0, 2 Pi}, {t[3, 6], 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

, where

```
v = r[1, 4] r[1, 6] r[3, 4] r[3, 6]
```

. The (still more challenging) nine-dimensional numerator integral is

```
NIntegrate[ Boole[ FullSimplify[A && B] ] v w, {U,0,1}, {r[1, 4], 0, 1}, {r[1, 6], 0, 1}, {r[3, 4], 0,1}, {r[3, 6], 0, 1}, {t[1, 4], 0, 2 Pi}, {t[1, 6], 0, 2 Pi}, {t[3, 4], 0, 2 Pi}, {t[3, 6], 0, 2 Pi}],
```

where

```
w = (56 U^2 ((-1 + U) (3 + U (178 + U (478 + U (178 + 3 U)))) - 60 U (1 + U) (1 + U (5 + U)) Log[U]))/(-1 + U)^9
```

, the integral of which over $U \in [0,1]$ is 1.

However, since the angular `t[i,j]` variables are not present in the integrands (`v`,  `w`), and only in the constraints (`A`, `B`), and only there in the form

```
Cos[t[1, 4] - t[1, 6] - t[3, 4] + t[3, 6]]
```

it seems that we can make a transformation

```
Cos[t[1, 4] - t[1, 6] - t[3, 4] + t[3, 6]] -> T
```

and let `T` range from $-1$ to $1$ and essentially remove from consideration the individual `t[i,j]`'s, particularly in light of our interest solely in the ratio of the two integrals.

So, in light of these last remarks I want to estimate the ratio of

```
NIntegrate[r[1,4] r[1,6] r[3,4] r[3,6] (56 U^2 ((-1+U) (3+U (178+U (478+U (178+3 U))))-60 U (1+U) (1+U (5+U)) Log[U]))/(-1+U)^9Boole[r[1,4]^2+r[3,4]^2<1&&(-1+r[1,6]^2) (-1+r[3,4]^2)+2 (1-2 TT) r[1,4] r[1,6] r[3,4] r[3,6]+r[1,4]^2 (-1+r[3,6]^2)>r[3,6]^2&&r[1,4]^2+U r[1,6]^2<1&&U (1+r[1,6]^2 (-U+r[3,4]^2)+2 (1-2 TT) r[1,4] r[1,6] r[3,4] r[3,6]-r[3,6]^2+r[1,4]^2 (-1+r[3,6]^2))>r[3,4]^2],{U,0,1},{r[1,4],0,1},{r[3,4],0,1},{r[3,6],0,1},{TT,0,1},{r[1,6],0,1}]
```

to

```
NIntegrate[r[1,4] r[1,6] r[3,4] r[3,6]Boole[r[1,4]^2+r[3,4]^2<1&&(-1+r[1,6]^2) (-1+r[3,4]^2)+2 (1-2 TT) r[1,4] r[1,6] r[3,4] r[3,6]+r[1,4]^2 (-1+r[3,6]^2)>r[3,6]^2],{r[1,4],0,1},{r[3,4],0,1},{r[3,6],0,1},{TT,0,1},{r[1,6],0,1}]  ,
```

where various `NIntegrate` options can be explored. (Also, I had made the additional transformation  `T -> (2 TT-1)`, so all variables lie in [0,1].)

My best current estimate of the ratio is 0.682442--rather close to the presumed target of 0.659488--but certainly not close enough for good support of the hypothesis.

Comment: I think you would get more responses if there was a specific question asked or if you could be explicit where *Mathematica* gives an error or warning or just doesn't seem to complete a command.  Having all of the statements in code form would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, JimB. I added code statements at end--looking for the best/computable estimates of the ratio--but not sure if there can be much substantial change from the current estimate of 0.682442.

Comment: I think a complete set of reproducible commands is still missing.  `Cos[t[1, 4] - t[1, 6] - t[3, 4] + t[3, 6]]->T` and `T->(2 TT-1)` should be made explicit.  All of the initial stuff you given could be eliminated.  Also, have you increased the working precision in the integrals with `WorkingPrecision->30` as you must be getting warnings that "Numerical integration converging too slowly...WorkingPrecision too small"?  Such information is essential to getting good help.

Comment: If I'm going to make this Cos[t[1, 4] - t[1, 6] - t[3, 4] + t[3, 6]]->T transformation, I guess I have to incorporate a suitable jacobian. I'll see what I can do, and whether I can still sensibly cut down the number of angular (t[i,j]) variables. Back to the drawing board, it seems.

Comment: If I transform  the cosine argument t[1, 4] - t[1, 6] - t[3, 4] + t[3, 6] to $\tau$, say, and integrate over $\tau \in [-2 \pi, 2 \pi]$, discarding the t[i,j]'s from the integration, I get the closest ratio value, 0.67696, yet to 0.659488, but can't really vouch for the soundness of doing so.